# How are sound waveforms stored and then displayed on SoundCloud?

Tags: javascript, audio, rendering, soundcloud

I'm particularly interested in how SoundCloud both stores and then displays their waveforms. As I scale my browser, I notice that the waveform itself actually scales accordingly, which means that they're not using prebaked images. Is there a library available in JavaScript which renders them, and if so, what format are they storing the data in?

Comment: The waveform, according to firebug, is a `canvas` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They actually save a large png image. You can get the image using soundcloud API.
Here is a link to a sample waveform image: http://w1.sndcdn.com/xleqtH0zXSlW_m.png

```
  SC.get(PATH
      , function(tracks, err){
        // tracks.waveform_url is the URL to a waveform png img
        $("#img").attr("src", tracks.waveform_url);
    });
```

you can see and example of how to obtain and display the waveform image here:
http://runnable.com/UuiebAIv7aAlAAB2/get-a-tracks-waveform-on-soundcloud-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

The waveform is actually stored as an image. SoundCloud.com (the website formerly known as “the Next Soundcloud”) uses the data extracted from the image to draw the waveform on the canvas.  This conversion was done on the front end at first, but this was moved to a back-end service for performance reasons.

Comment: Any idea as to how they take a PNG image and transform them into scalable graphics?

Comment: Basically just analyse each column of pixels. An open source implementation of that is [Waveform.js](http://www.waveformjs.org/), you might want to take a look at that.